# restoring (.backup file) in postgres

Tags: postgresql

[image]

how to over come with this restoring problem

Comment: How did you create that backup? **[edit]** your question and add the exact command you used to create the backup file. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). [edit] your question, do not post code or additional information in comments.

Comment: postgres 8.4 ?.. your post need some story beside the screenshot...

Comment: `pg_restore` is your friend. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/app-pgrestore.html